# java8 lambdas compile error when use consumer

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

```
consumerConfig.subscribe(
  regClient -> regClient.onDiscoveryEvent(
        Constants.PROVIDER_ADD_EVENT, 
        ssfurl-> System.out.println(ssfurl))
);
```

java compiled error.

```
Error:(172, 72) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:  method onDiscoveryEvent(java.lang.String,(ssfurl)->[...]furl))
location: java.lang.Object regClient
```

but when i changed to Anonymous class.it worded.why?

thanks.

bellow code compiled ,no problem.

```
        consumerConfig.subscribe(new Consumer<RegClient>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(RegClient regClient) {
                regClient.onDiscoveryEvent(Constants.PROVIDER_ADD_EVENT, ssfurl -> System.out.println(ssfurl));
            }
        });
```

---

ConsumerConfig method

```
 public List<Provider> subscribe(Consumer<RegClient> callback){
    List<RegistryConfig> registryConfigs = getRegistries();
    if (registryConfigs == null || registryConfigs.isEmpty()){
        throw new InitException("reg center address is empty");
    }
    List<Provider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (RegistryConfig config:registryConfigs){
        RegClient regClient = RegClientFactory.getRegClient(config.getRegisterAddresses());
        List<SSFURL> ssfurls = regClient.subscribe(buildSubscribeURL()).getProviderList();
        callback.accept(regClient);
        if (ssfurls != null && !ssfurls.isEmpty()){
            providers.addAll(getSubscribeProviders(ssfurls));
        }
    }
    return providers;
}
```

---

RegClient's method.

public void onDiscoveryEvent(String eventKey,DiscoveryEvent event)

the DiscoverEvent interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface DiscoveryEvent {


    /**
     * service provider add or remove
     *
     * @param ssfurl
     */
    public void discovery(SSFURL ssfurl);


}
```

Comment: You should post the working version and the compiler error message. I cannot clearly understand what your code is supposed to do, but the syntax looks wrong.

Comment: They both work for me. Post your `consumerConfig` declaration.

Comment: I suspect you have a raw type somewhere that's messing with the lambda's type inference.